# Mongod in recovering after enabling security in mongod.conf

Tags: mongodb

Created 2 shards with 3 node replica set.

After enabling the security in mongod.conf file, every node was in recovering state. But if we disable/comment out in the mongod.conf file the nodes were normal.

All nodes were running on AWS.
**OS:** CentOS 7
**Mongodb Version:** 3.6.2

**Background:** Before enabling the security, I created a user as below.

```
db.createUser( { user: "cxiroot",
                 pwd: "root",
                  roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" }] },
               { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 } );
```

I am able to authenticate with, `db.auth("cxiroot","root")`

After enabling security and restarting the service, all nodes were in *recovering state.*

Basically I am trying to do `db.shutdownServer()` by enabling security.

**Log reporting:**

```
2019-10-17T11:40:23.138-0400 I REPL_HB  [replexec-1] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 1934) to 109.99.16.36:27018, response status: Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetHeartbeat: "shard1rs", configVersion: 4, hbv: 1, from: "109.99.16.112:27018", fromId: 1, term: 128, $replData: 1, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1571326818, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 466B43AC8CDFBE9B5CBEA8AC4860925560B63296), keyId: 6745513220909301779 } }, $db: "admin" }
2019-10-17T11:40:23.150-0400 I ACCESS   [conn2] Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetHeartbeat: "shard1rs", configVersion: 4, hbv: 1, from: "109.99.16.137:27018", fromId: 2, term: 128, $replData: 1, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1571326818, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 466B43AC8CDFBE9B5CBEA8AC4860925560B63296), keyId: 6745513220909301779 } }, $db: "admin" }
```

mongod.conf

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /mongodb/data/logs/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /mongodb/data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

net:
  port: 27018
  bindIp: x.x.x.x

security:
  authorization: 'enabled'

replication:
 replSetName: shard1rs

sharding:
 clusterRole: shardsvr
```

What's causing this problem?.

Comment: please provide the mongod.conf file details.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Thanks Pramod.  So, when sharding client applications are expected to connect to a MONGOS, not a MONGOD.  The shard is comprised of multiple MONGOD called a replica set.  The replica set members need to synchronize internally.  By placing the 'authorization' option in the config file for the replica set MONGOD members you are saying they must authenticate against each other by means of a username password mechanism, which I don't believe is supported.  The option you added is expected to be applied to the config file of the MONGOS.

Comment: For replica set member authentication the easiest method is keyfile, but x509 cert based auth is also an option.  See MongoDB docs at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/

Comment: If you have no security on the MONGOD and you are sharded users could accidentally connect to a MONGOD and bypass data distribution provided by the MONGOS and the config servers.  This is a very good reason why keyfile or x509 should be applied to MONGOD servers.

Comment: From this documentation, it says security.authorization is only available for mongod. [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization)

Comment: I will do some research and reply...

Comment: If you enable access control for users you also need to enable access control for communication between replica set members: [Update Replica Set to Keyfile Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/).

Comment: Will try and update.

Comment: Hi Pramod, I did some verification.  I see that with mongo 4.0 you can have a sharded cluster with no authentication.  This is not best practices and results in an unsecure environment but shows the communication between all the nodes is available.  Conversely if you choose to secure the system you need to choose keyfile or x509 for intercommunications.  If you do this then the MONGOS assumes security is enabled and requires authentication for most commands.  You can still connect without username or password but you will need to authenticate at some point to do anything real.

Comment: More verification.  If the MONGOD has the following configuration option... `security:
  keyFile: /var/run/mongodb/mykeyfile` then it acts as if it has `authorization: 'enabled'`

Comment: From this documentation [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/) Seems like, if we have sharded cluster with replica set then keyfile property in security must have "Internal Authentication" enabled to communicate securely among all nodes and this will automatically enable the "user access control". But "user access control" with alone "authorization: enabled" property in security cannot work in cluster environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 2019-10-22:**

OP asked to change ports to reflect MongoDB recommendations.  It took a bit of digging to find any recommendations from MongoDB.  For all modern versions (i.e., 3.6 or later) there is no specific port recommended.  Going back to 3.0 docs, however, the default port for config servers is documented as 27019.  https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/ .  Looking at Ops Manager default deployments we see shard replica sets default to port 27018.

I assume these ports are selected to help protect developers who are writing connection strings and consuming the database from accidentally connecting to a replica set directly, and bypassing the MongoDB router MONGOS.  OK, so below I have changed the ports respectively...

---

Here are instructions to setup 10 hosts to run a 2-shard sharded cluster on AWS.  These instructions describe hardware setup only, and do not describe how to select a proper shard key to apply to data.  The instructions setup the hardware but have no data.  The breakdown of servers is as follows...

1 host for MONGOS

3 hosts for shard config server replica set - each host has a MONGOD installed.

3 hosts for shard0 replica set - each host has a MONGOD installed.

3 hosts for shard1 replica set - each host has a MONGOD installed.

This setup assumes a keyfile will be used for internal authentication.  The keyfile is a shared secret stored in a file on all 10 hosts.  When using keyfile authentication treat the keyfile like a password.  It should be protected.

### Generate a keyfile:

```
openssl rand -base64 741 > mykeyfile
```

for the sake of this tutorial assume the keyfile generated is ...

```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```

I generated this using the command above.  It is random and only used for this tutorial.

### Install MongoDB:

This example uses MongoDB Enterprise.  This version requires a license purchased from MongoDB.  To use the Community edition change the repo definition.

This example assumes AWS hosts are AMI2 Amazon Linux.

Run this command on all 10 hosts.

```
echo '[mongodb-enterprise]
name=MongoDB Enterprise Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.com/yum/amazon/2/mongodb-enterprise/4.0/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc' | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-enterprise.repo

sudo yum -y install mongodb-enterprise
```

### Distribute the keyfile to all hosts:

On all 10 AWS hosts issue the following...

```
echo "bgi+xXyBAHtNXmQnTjDNrSyTa+I9SGQXbBZONHRxHxKw2y/M3kGtpiJCVCyI+bDk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" | sudo tee /var/run/mongodb/mykeyfile

sudo chown mongod.mongod /var/run/mongodb/mykeyfile
sudo chmod 400 /var/run/mongodb/mykeyfile
```

### Setup the Config Servers:

Select 3 AWS instances as the config servers.  On these three hosts run the following...

```
sudo rm /etc/mongod.conf


echo "systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

net:
  port: 27019
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security:
  keyFile: /var/run/mongodb/mykeyfile

replication:
  replSetName: configrs

sharding:
  clusterRole: configsvr
" | sudo tee /etc/mongod.conf


sudo systemctl start mongod
```

On the final config server log into the mongo shell...

```
mongo
```

and initiate the replica set.  This example uses host names from my AWS instances.  Change the host names to match yours.  Notice the name of the replica set is `configrs`.

```
rs.initiate(
    {
        _id: "configrs",
        version: 1,
        members: [
            { _id: 0, host: "ip-172-31-27-98.us-west-2.compute.internal:27019" },
            { _id: 1, host: "ip-172-31-17-202.us-west-2.compute.internal:27019" },
            { _id: 2, host: "ip-172-31-19-63.us-west-2.compute.internal:27019" }
        ]
    }
)
```

Add credentials to allow root level access for administration.  If the prompt says `'SECONDARY'` then wait about 1 minute.  Test by issuing command `use admin`.  Continue to wait until it says `'PRIMARY'`.  If it never says `'PRIMARY'` you have problems and cannot proceed.

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: "barry", pwd: "mypassword", roles: [{role: "root", db: "admin"}]})
db.auth("barry", "mypassword")
```

### Configure Shard0:

Identify another 3 hosts for shard0.

Run the following on all 3 hosts...

```
sudo rm /etc/mongod.conf

echo "systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

net:
  port: 27018
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security:
  keyFile: /var/run/mongodb/mykeyfile

replication:
  replSetName: shard0

sharding:
  clusterRole: shardsvr
" | sudo tee /etc/mongod.conf


sudo systemctl start mongod
```

On the final host log into the mongo shell...

```
mongo
```

Initiate the replica set.  Notice replica set name `shard0`.  Replace host names with yours...

```
rs.initiate(
    {
        _id: "shard0",
        version: 1,
        members: [
            { _id: 0, host: "ip-172-31-21-228.us-west-2.compute.internal:27018" },
            { _id: 1, host: "ip-172-31-17-221.us-west-2.compute.internal:27018" },
            { _id: 2, host: "ip-172-31-17-145.us-west-2.compute.internal:27018" }
        ]
    }
)
```

... and create root user...

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: "barry", pwd: "mypassword", roles: [{role: "root", db: "admin"}]})
db.auth("barry", "mypassword")
```

### Configure shard1:

Select 3 remaining hosts for shard1 and apply these settings to all 3...

```
sudo rm /etc/mongod.conf

echo "systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

net:
  port: 27018
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security:
  keyFile: /var/run/mongodb/mykeyfile

replication:
  replSetName: shard1

sharding:
  clusterRole: shardsvr
" | sudo tee /etc/mongod.conf


sudo systemctl start mongod
```

On the final of these 3 start the mongo shell ...

```
mongo
```

... and initialize the replica set.  Notice replica set name `shard1`.  Replace host names with yours...

```
rs.initiate(
    {
        _id: "shard1",
        version: 1,
        members: [
            { _id: 0, host: "ip-172-31-30-65.us-west-2.compute.internal:27018" },
            { _id: 1, host: "ip-172-31-17-88.us-west-2.compute.internal:27018" },
            { _id: 2, host: "ip-172-31-23-140.us-west-2.compute.internal:27018" }
        ]
    }
)
```

On the final of the 3 create a root user...

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: "barry", pwd: "mypassword", roles: [{role: "root", db: "admin"}]})
db.auth("barry", "mypassword")
```

### Setup MONGOS:

On the final host reserved for the MONGOS router create a MONGOS config file.  Change host names on references to config servers to match your implementation.

```
echo "systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

net:
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  port: 27017

sharding:
  configDB: configrs/ip-172-31-27-98.us-west-2.compute.internal:27019,ip-172-31-17-202.us-west-2.compute.internal:27019,ip-172-31-19-63.us-west-2.compute.internal:27019

security:
  keyFile: /var/run/mongodb/mykeyfile
" | sudo tee /etc/mongos.conf
```

Create systemd script to start the MONGOS using the user 'mongod'.

```
echo '[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server Router
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongos.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongos
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongos $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid
Type=forking
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false
# Recommended limits for for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
' | sudo tee /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongos.service
```

Reload the systemctl daemon and start the MONGOS.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start mongos
```

If you prefer to start MONGOS manually instead of using systemd scripts use the following command...  This is optional.

```
sudo -u mongod mongos -f /etc/mongos.conf
```

On the host having the MONGOS log into the mongo shell and authenticate...

```
mongo
use admin
db.auth("barry", "mypassword")
```

Initialize the sharding.  Only one host is needed.  Mongo will discover all the other hosts in the shard.  Change host names to match yours...

```
sh.addShard("shard0/ip-172-31-21-228.us-west-2.compute.internal:27018") 
sh.addShard("shard1/ip-172-31-30-65.us-west-2.compute.internal:27018")
```

View the status of the sharding...

```
sh.status()
```

At this point sharding is prepared.  No data is on these hosts.  No databases or collections have been told to shard.  No shard key has been established.  These instructions are merely for setting up hardware using keyfile internal authentication.  See MongoDB instructions for sharding databases

### Conclusion:

If we utilize keyfile internal authentication the entire cluster requires user authorization to perform tasks.  System administrators can choose to implement SCRAM-SHA username/password authentication mechanisms for users, or can use x.509 Certificate based authentication, or others.  If your cluster was not using any security, applying keyfile internal authentication may cause surprise as client authentication is now required.  My testing showed if I applied `authorization: 'enabled'` while keyfile was defined there was no change in behavior.  Example:

```
security:
  keyFile: /var/run/mongodb/mykeyfile
```

... behaved the same as ...

```
security:
  keyFile: /var/run/mongodb/mykeyfile
  authorization: 'enabled'
```

Comment: Can you update the answer with, different port like 27017 for mongos.conf, 27018 for mongod.conf, 27019 form mongodconf.conf [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/) so that it won't be confusing to any others and also make a note for going to "Internal Authentication" in cluster environment stating it will enable both security among nodes and user access control.

Comment: @Pramod - Updated ports as requested.  Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @Pramod - Nice find.  ;)  - fixed.